# Call jquery function from MVC Action method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-calendar-api

```
function AddScheduledCandidate() {

if (ValidateScheduledCandidate()) {
    InsertGoogleEvent($('#comment').val(), $('#SchDateTime').val() );

    $.post(WebsiteURL + 'VideoRepository/AddScheduledCandidate', { id: $('#hdnId').val() }, "json")
                            .done(function (response) {

                                    window.location.href = response.Url;
                            })
    }
}
```

The problem in above code is that my page is redirected before google calender info is inserted. It is because I know jquery code doesn't execute line by line and before completing google calendar event, redirect code is fired and google calendar record is not inserted.
Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can u post code for insertgoogleevent?

Comment: Title and question seems to be contradictory:)

Comment: I wrote that title because if I can call javascript from mvc action, the page redirect would not have been happened until the script execution is completed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems insertgoogle event is async server call so try something like below to sync call .

```
function AddScheduledCandidate() {

if (ValidateScheduledCandidate()) {


$.post(WebsiteURL + 'VideoRepository/AddScheduledCandidate', { id: $('#hdnId').val() }, "json")
                        .done(function (response) {

 InsertGoogleEvent($('#comment').val(), $('#SchDateTime').val() );
                           window.location.href = response.Url;
                        })
}
}
```

Comment: You also need to put window.location.href in call back of insertgoogleevent function

Comment: I can't do so because I am using the same script in another pages as well.

Comment: @NadeemShaikh then you need to add some flag to function parameter to identify who is caller and make if condition based bahaviour there.